# "SingleIdentityLoginModule missing console.username paramater" on FormBasedAuthenticator Mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using a FormBasedAuthenticator with SingleIdentityLoginModule on IBM MobileFirst platform v7.0.

```
    <realm loginModule="StrongDummy" name="PageAccess">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>

    <loginModule name="StrongDummy" expirationInSeconds="-1">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>
```

I'm invoking this as seen below:

```
    var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
    var options = {};
    options.parameters = {
        j_username : "admin",
        j_password : "admin"
    };
    options.headers = {};
    sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, $rootScope.sampleAppRealmChallengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);
```

When I try to login using any credentials it shows an error "SingleIdentityLoginModule missing console.username paramater".

I'm not sure what I'm missing here or where to put that "console.username" parameter.

Please see attached image.

[image: Login Form]

Answer (score 0):

The single identity login module is used to grant access to a protected resource to a single user, the identity of which is defined in the worklight.properties file. Use this module only for test purposes.

More details in the link [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_single_identity_login_module.html).